# Finding the version of dojo through IBM BPM 8

Tags: javascript, dojo, business-process-management

I am working on creating a process flow using IBM BPM 8 on a dojo platform which encompasses the use of javascript. We have in use three versions that supports NextGen coaches; Heritage coaches and Portal versions. Now through this, we are trying to implement a calendar view like that of FullCalendar or one like that of SharePoint. The group that I am working with is uncertain of how to incorporate the code function dojo.version.toString() in order to yield the results we want. I do have examples of what I have tried but am unsure of exact syntax due to using different tools.

Below are a few examples of what I have tried. Such a call is a little more out of my knowledge of what to do or the syntax to use, so laugh if you want, wont take offense, but I do hope to get some help or at least guided where I can get some help.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
getVersion(){
            alert(“Version: “ + dojo.version.toString());
}
</script>
<input type=”button” onclick=”getVersion()”>Get Version</input>
```

RESULT: nothing

```
var foo: String=dojo.version.toString();
```

RESULT: nothing

```
var string=dojo.version.toString();
```

RESULT: nothing

```
var string=dojo.version.toString();
<button type="button">Get Version</button>;
```

RESULT: nothing

I am not the most savvy of programmers and have been directed by the group to just look up if there have been successes in this realm but have found a few that looked promising but when I try it out myself, everything works except for the version not appearing.

Thank you for your time and consideration. Any and all information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure of your setup, but if you browse to:

http://dojotoolkit.org/

And then either in Firebug's console for Firefox, or Chrome developer tools' console, type this:

```
dojo.version.toString()
```

Then press enter, you will get (something like) this:

```
"1.8.3 (30226)"
```

[image]

To get this working in your code, you would use the following assignment:

```
var dojoVersion = dojo.version.toString();
```

Or in the style of your example

```
<script>
function getDojoVersion() {
    alert("Version: " + dojo.version.toString());
}
</script>
<button onclick="getDojoVersion()">Get Version</button>
```

**Off topic:** I think some of your double quotes have pasted incorrectly, and I don't think they are valid JavaScript as they are.

**Off topic:** The `<input>` tag is not supposed to have any content.

Answer (score 0):

dojo **1.7.3** is used in IBM BPM 8, if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

IBM BPM 8, 8.0.1 and 8.0.1.1 all use the dojo version 1.7.3. IBM BPM 8.0.1.2 now uses 1.7.4. However, these dojo builds are IBM customized. They are not necessarily the ones released officially by dojo. Many of their features are specific for IBM BPM.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you posted this question
If you still in need or maybe someone else who has the same issue
you can use **Firebug** onload it will give you which version is used

***dojo version used by Coach is: 1.8.6***